# Split the string and use it for checking the checkboxes

Tags: jquery

UPDATE: Here is the working code, thanks King King for your inputs, appreciate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/q2WBG/7/

This might be a bad question to ask but I am getting it hard to do. I have a string which is like below:

```
dataType=type:Cricket+type:Football+type:Hockey
```

Now what I want to do is to extract the "Cricket", "Football", and "Hockey" and then run the for loop to select the corresponding check boxes on my page. I have achieved the second part of the problem, i.e. to check the checkboxes, but now I need to do it dynamically, where in I have to first extract the above values. I tried following code, but it didn't work.

I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/q2WBG/6/

```
<div id="here"></div>
```

```js
var str = "dataType=type:Cricket+type:Football+type:Hockey";
var valNew = str.split('type:');

for (var i = 0; i < valNew.length; i++){
    $('#here').html(valNew);
}
```

I have commented this portion of the code in fiddle, can you provide the fix?

Comment: `var valNew = str1.split(/[=+]type:/);` and then loop from the value `1` (not from `0`).

Answer (score 0):

```
var valNew = str1.split('type:');

//we know that the 'type' can never be before type: so we start at 1
for (var i = 1; i < valNew.length; i++) {
    //if there is a plus, then we remove it, otherwise it'll just skip the replace
    alert(valNew[i].replace('+', ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8uv3y/1/)**
 Try this

```
var str = "dataType=type:Cricket+type:Football+type:Hockey";

var valNew = str.split(/[=+]type:/);


for (var i = 1; i < valNew.length; i++) {

    $('#' + valNew[i]).attr("checked", true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwcoffey/4uKG5/1/

And the salient code:

```
var valNew = str1.replace(/^dataType=type:/, '').split('+type:');
for (var i = 0; i < valNew.length; i++) {
    $('#' + valNew[i]).prop("checked", true);
}
```

I fixed two things:

**First:** we parse the string like this:

1.Remove the 'dataType=type:' from the beginning. Now we have just:
2. Split on '+type:'

**Second:** I changed `'#here'` to `'#' + valNew[i]` so it targets the checkbox properly.

Answer (score 0):

I like when regex comes to help :D

```
   var pattern = '/(?<=:)[\w]+/ig';
```

This will match all the words after ':'

dataType=type:**Cricket**+type:**Football**+type:**Hockey**